# Finding multiple values using map-reduce

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

Let's say i have an rdd with the following schema :

```
(ID,VALUE_1,VALUE_2)
```

What i would like to do is somehow using map_reduce end up with something like :

`(ID,SUM(VALUE_1),SUM(VALUE_2),rdd_size)` where `sum(value_1,2)` is the sum of the value_1 or _2 for the whole rdd and `rdd_size` is the number of rows in my rdd.

So far using reduce i can easily find one of those 3 but i can't seem to end with the desired output schema.Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Please note this is in Scala but you could do similar in PySpark as well.

Following code creates the RDD the way you have shown

```
scala> val list = List((1,2,3),(1,3,4),(1,10,23),(2,3,5),(2,55,6))
list: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (1,3,4), (1,10,23), (2,3,5), (2,55,6))

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(list)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[11] at parallelize at <console>:26
```

*Map* this RDD to output (key,value) where key is the first element in tuple ( in your case ID) and the value is Tuple3 where first element is hardcoded to 1 and rest two elements are copied from original RDD ( VALUE_1 and VALUE_2 in your example). RDD collect and println are included below for understanding. It is not advisable when you run this with real data.

```
scala> val rdd1 = rdd.map(x => (x._1,(1,x._2,x._3)))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Int, Int, Int))] = MapPartitionsRDD[8] at map at <console>:25

scala> rdd1.collect.foreach(println)
(1,(1,2,3))
(1,(1,3,4))
(1,(1,10,23))
(2,(1,3,5))
(2,(1,55,6))
```

*groupByKey* is not required in all of this but just wanted to display how the grouped RDD would look like.

```
scala> rdd1.groupByKey().collect.foreach(println)
(1,CompactBuffer((1,2,3), (1,3,4), (1,10,23)))
(2,CompactBuffer((1,3,5), (1,55,6)))
```

Run *reduceByKey* to arrive the output you are expecting.

You can use above groupBy output to sum the VALUE_1 and VALUE_2 to confirm results of reduceByKey are correct.

```
scala> rdd1.reduceByKey((a,b) => (a._1+b._1,a._2+b._2,a._3+b._3)).collect.foreach(println)
(1,(3,15,30))
(2,(2,58,11))
```

In the above output
Key is the ID in your example.
Value is Tuple3 where first element is number of records in that group, second element is SUM(VALUE_1) and third element is SUM(VALUE_2).
You can rearrange if you want number of records or size in your example as the last element in Tuple.